# WhatsApp delayed notifications - Force application to run with foreground priority

Tags: root-access, notifications, whatsapp-messenger, google-play-services, xposed-framework

Is it possible to force an application (e.g. WhatsApp) to run with foreground priority so Android shows notifications (e.g. new messages) of that app as fast as possible?
There are apps that use a persistent notifications to achieve this goal. Is there any way to do the same with apps of your choosing? Maybe through Tasker?

CM13 - GApps (pico) - Xposed - Root

Comment: There are some workarounds to use. Is your device tooted by the way?

Comment: I had to delete the solution probably its not working as hoped, but I am pretty sure it does on my device, maybe something going on on your device. Goodluck!